# How to pass url to partial/form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I would like to pass the url to a form, which is in a partial. However, the current setup generates an error message:

```
SyntaxError in OrganizationsController#new
syntax error, unexpected keyword_do, expecting keyword_end ...or(@organization), url="url" do |f| @output_buffer.safe_appe... ...
```

The error highlights the 3rd line of the partial/form which is `<%= form_for(@organization), url="url" do |f| %>`

Two views both use the partial/form, and to this end include:

```
## View1:
<%= render 'registrationform', local:{url: signup_checkout_path} %>
## View2 (url should point to `def create` in organizations controller):
<%= render 'registrationform', local:{url: organizations_path} %>
```

Routes includes:

```
resources :organizations
post 'signup/register'    => 'organizations#checkout', as: 'signup_checkout'
```

And the partial registrationform includes:

```
<% if local_assigns.has_key? :url %>
  <%= form_for(@organization), url="url" do |f| %>
  ...
<% else %>
  ????
<% end %>
```

`Def new` in the controller:

```
def new
  if (logged_in?)
    flash[:danger] = "You're already logged in"
    redirect_to root_url
  end
  @organization = Organization.new
  @member = @organization.members.build
end
```

Comment: Try this `<%= form_for @organization, url: url do |f| %>`, your `url` is a variable you passed as local, not the "url" string

Comment: Thanks, now indeed no error message anymore. However, it now shows the ???? in the else part of the partial (added to original post). Instead it should be showing the form. So apparantly the partial thinks it has no value for url?

Comment: It then produces the error `undefined local variable or method 'url' `

Comment: the word is `locals` not `local` while passing from page

Comment: In the view I changed it to locals:{url: organizations_path} and locals:{url: signup_checkout_path}. In the partial I've kept <% if local_assigns.has_key? :url %>. This produces no error but still has the same result where it show ???? from the else part in the partial.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77381/discussion-between-sontya-and-nick).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `local` to `locals`

```
## View1:
<%= render "registrationform", { url: signup_checkout_path } %>
## View2 (url should point to `def create` in organizations controller):
<%= render "registrationform", { url: organizations_path } %>
```

And pass `url` variable not "url" string

```
<% if local_assigns.has_key? :url %>
   <%= form_for @organization, url: url do |f| %>
   ...
<% else %>
   ????
<% end %>
```