# Rails: How to pass a url path to a form_for partial in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I'm trying to pass a `url` and `variable` to a form partial in Rails.

---

**Method #1:**
This works, but I'd rather not hardcode `post_create_path` into the form, so that it can be used for #update as well.

new.html.erb

```
<%= render partial: 'shared/form', locals: { form: @form } %>
```

_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for form, url: post_create_path do |f| %>
...
<% end %>
```

---

**Method #2:**
This does not work.

new.html.erb

```
<%= render partial: 'shared/form', locals: { form: @form, url: post_create_path } %>
```

_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for form, url: url do |f| %>
...
<% end %>
```

**Error:**

> undefined local variable or method `url' for #<#:0x007f8d4d831fd0>

**What I've also tried:**

1. Just `url` instead of `url:url` but getting the same error.
2. Following this thread: [How to pass url to partial/form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30138927/how-to-pass-url-to-partial-form)

I've been trying to make this work for a couple hours now and feel like I'm running out of options to try. Any help in pointing out what I'm doing wrong would be super appreciated!

Comment: did you try renaming url to different variable? maybe there is issue with the actual "url" word?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can use different actions by opening `form_for` on edit and new view templates and then pass the form object to the partial which contains all the fields of the form that are common to both create and update

new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @post, :url => { :action => "create" } do |form| %>
  <%= render partial: 'shared/form', locals: { f: form } %>
```

edit.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @post, :url => { :action => "update" } do |form| %>
  <%= render partial: 'shared/form', locals: { f: form } %>
```

shared/_form.html.erb

```
  <%= f.text_field :title %>
  ...
  <%= f.submit "Save" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `locals` hash as a `form_for` argument:

```rb
# new.html.erb
<%= render partial: 'shared/form', form: @form, locals: { url: post_create_path, method: :post} %>

# edit.html.erb
<%= render partial: 'shared/form', form: @form, locals: { url: post_update_path, method: :put} %>

# _form.html.erb
<%= form_for form, locals do |f| %>
...
<% end %>
```

`locals` is just a hash and you can give it any name (like `vars`). Then use it consistently in the views and the form.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same challenge when working on a Rails application with **namespaced routes**, but [sa77's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39737108/10907864) helped me.

Just to add to it.

My `routes` file is like this:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :users do
    resources :students
  end
end
```

So my `new.html.erb` was modified like this:

```
<h1>New User</h1>

<%= form_with(model: @user, url: users_students_path, local: true) do |form| %>
  <%= render partial: 'form', user: @user, locals: { form: form } %>
<% end %>

<%= link_to 'Back', users_students_path %>
```

And my `edit.html.erb` was modified like this:

```
<h1>Editing User</h1>

<%= form_with(model: @user, url: users_student_path(@user), local: true) do |form| %>
  <%= render partial: 'form', user: @user, locals: { form: form } %>
<% end %>

<%= link_to 'Show', users_student_path %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', users_students_path %>
```

And then my `_form.html.erb` file was modified like this:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= form.label :email %>
  <%= form.text_field :email %>
</div>

<div class="field">
  <%= form.label :password %>
  <%= form.text_field :password %>
</div>

<div class="actions">
  <%= form.submit %>
</div>
```

That's all.

**I hope this helps**